# htaccess 301 redirect to language subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I change the site url to accept diferent languages, So, I move the site content for default language

from: www.site.com to: www.site.com/en

Now, I doing the redirect from php, if `$_GET['lang']` not exist or `$_GET['path']` exist, redirect to site.com/en or site.com/en/(path) but I thinking a 301 redirect from root to the folder is better.

How can I write this rule?

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ php/download.php?id=$1 [L]

# with language
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/p/(.*)$ single.php?lang=$1&hash=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thanks

Comment: Need some clarity. What are example of URLs and how those URLs should be handled.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, this would do what you want.

**`Updated .htaccess`** (with comments for better understanding)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the hostname is a `www` subdomain, redirect to the parent domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Internal rewrite of Download request URL to download PHP script
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ php/download.php?id=$1 [L]

# If request path is just root `/` (redirect to default language site)
RewriteRule ^$  /en [R=301,L]

# If request path is a language code,
# internally rewrite to index.php with `lang` query paramater
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})$ index.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# If request path begins with lang code and has a hash segment,
# internally rewrite to single.php with `lang` and `hash` query parameters
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/p/(.*)$ single.php?lang=$1&hash=$2 [L]

# If request path begins with lang code and has additional segements
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)$ index.php?lang=$1&path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

# For every other request path not having a language code,
# if path is not an existing file or directory,
# redirect to a path prefixing default lang code before the requested path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$  /en/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```